# Zf2 MasterSlaveFeature different Slaves

Tags: zend-framework2

is it possible to use different Slave-Connections by using the MasterSlaveFeature in a TableGateway?

I successfully managed to implement the MasterSlaveFeature with one Slave.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible. If you look at the [MasterSlaveFeature code](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/TableGateway/Feature/MasterSlaveFeature.php) you see there is only one $slaveAdapter possible.

If you would like to have a "MultipleMasterSlaveFeature", I guess you have to write it by your own.

You should have a good strategy in mind to select one of your slave adapters, e.g. random select, time dependend or another strategy...

Such class could look like the following code...

```
class MultipleMasterSlaveFeature extends AbstractFeature {

    // Array with AdapterInterface objects
    protected $slaveAdpters = null;

    //
    protected $masterSql = null;

    //
    protected $slaveSql = null;

    /**
     * 
     * @param array $slaveAdapters
     * @param Sql $slaveSql
     */
    public __construct(array $slaveAdapters, $slaveSql = null) 
    {

        $this->slaveAdapters = $slaveAdapters;

        if ($slaveSql) {
            $this->slaveSql = $slaveSql;
        }       
    }

    // ...


    /**
     * after initialization, retrieve the original adapter as "master"
     */
    public function postInitialize()
    {

        // Select one of the specified slave adapters
        // .. depending on timestamp
        $selectedSlaveAdapter = (count($this->slaveAdapters) == 0) ? null : $this->slaveAdapters[time() % count($this->slaveAdapters)];

        // ..from MasterSlaveFeature class
        $this->masterSql = $this->tableGateway->sql;
        if ($this->slaveSql == null) {
            $this->slaveSql = new Sql(
                $selectedSlaveAdapter,
                $this->tableGateway->sql->getTable(),
                $this->tableGateway->sql->getSqlPlatform()
            );
        }
    }


    // .. preSelect() and postSelect() from MasterSlaveFeature class
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will give it a try the next days.